# Opening tab when page loads

Tags: javascript, html

I am currenly using this:
[JS Tabs](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_tabs)
and would like to add onto it so that when the page loads with a  it will open the corresponding tab.

e.g.loading the url `gallery.php#london` will open `<li><a href="#london" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</a></li>`

I cannot seem to figure out how while also keeping the `onclick="openCity(event, 'London')"` working too.

Any help or advice would be amazing, thank you!

Comment: If you got your answer, please select it as **Answer**. So, no more developers spend time on this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this at the end of your page:

```
<script>
openCity('click', 'London');
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you :) Would it work with all three? I have 3 links each going to the same page but each would open a different tab.

Comment: @NaomiWilliams, Yes. Change the London to your desired link in each page. By the way, you can try it yourself